# Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure not making it to output dir even with Copy Local=true

Tags: ninject, ninject.web

After installing Ninject.web and compiled the site on my local development PC it works.
But when it is compiled, after the commit, with the server build in release mode,in the bin folder is missing only microsoft.web.infrastrucure.

Also does not run the registration HttpModule for Ninject.

I do not know what to do!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. I had Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure referenced in a class library. I had to reference it in my Web Application project as well to get it to publish a release build.

Comment: Would add that the website, at boot compiles without errors, but throws an error at run-time because there is no http module to be attached to the request.